# How to define the main data post body that's belong to Post page in blogger?

Tags: post, blogger

I'm trying to define the real  `<data:post.body/>` that's belong to the post page in Blogger, So I can add the read more script and put the Adsense in the middle of the body, and if you can tell me more about it?! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

login to your blogger account > Template > Edit Html , now try to find the `<data:post.body/>` if you are using the simple blogger template you will find 3 of them the first one following to this line `<b:includable id='mobile-post' var='post'>`about 39 lines between.this data post body belong to the mobile template as it says. Click Enter to go to the other result of search you will find two data post body close from each others the below one is respon to convert the data of your post to shows it as text in your post page the middle one is respon about your post page following to "includable id=post" 34 lines between , If you are using another custom blogger template try to delete every one Separately when you delete two of them and see the result (nothing will happen) the meant data post body will delete your written content in your blog post page , Don't worry when you Undo this transaction the content shows up.

Now we know the main data post body code of your post page , **If you add something before this code it will shows up above your content=under post title**

**if you add something after this code will shows up below your content=end of your post**

*to add the read more and adsense code in the middle of your post first set up the read more script you will find the data post body splitted to three the followed by quot item quot is the one, replace it to adsense in the middle code.*

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: you want a read-more script to run on an ITEM/STATIC-PAGE page type, or do you want the read-more script to run on an INDEX page type? And what do you mean that you're trying to "define" it? data:post.body goes within the post includable.